# How to test Azure function with multiple parameters

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

Via Azure Functions Core Tools I managed to test functions with 1 parameter, for instance http://localhost:7071/api/CheckMail?email=Test@test.test.

But I have not yet found how I test a function when I add a second parameter.
Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `&` character to add aditional parameters:
`http://localhost:7071/api/CheckMail?email=Test@test.test&name=bartvd`

> In the example URL below, multiple query parameters are separated by the ampersand, `&`:
>
> `http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret&color=purple`
>
> The order of the queries doesn't matter (`name=ferret&color=purple` and `color=purple&name=ferret` both produce the same results) and the exact structure of the query string is not standardized. Methods used to parse the query string may differ between websites.

More information: [Query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)